# upload youtube video server side

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

In my application, the user can upload a video directly to my youtube channel to make it public.

[image]

- The client part of my application acquires the video and uploads it to my server.
- My server then uses Youtube API to upload the video to **my** youtube channel.

And here is how I implemented it:

1. Created a new project: https://console.developers.google.com/project
2. Enabled `YouTube Data API v3`:
   [image]
3. Created a `Key for server applications`:
   [image]
4. Here's my java code:

   ```
   YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
       @Override
       public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

       }
   })//
   .setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer("XXXX"))//same as above
   .setApplicationName("Some Name")//is it important?
   .build();
   ```

The rest of the java code is the same as the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video)

But I can't get this to work, and I'm getting:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException code:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
```

Any idea why? What Can I check?

Is the API KEY sufficient here ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a full OAuth for this, also use as installed application rather server application. And user has to go through OAuth2. Service accounts are not supported in Data API v3.

More info:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

You can check Java samples here: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java

Comment: well my users are not required to have youtube accounts, so they cannot go through OAuth2 as it's my youtube account not theirs.

Comment: then you'll once go through OAuth2 and then you'll be done. Or get your token from playground and use that token for the YouTube API. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/