# Youtube API Key

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

When I try to use YouTube API for Search, I get this error:

> There was a service error: 403 : The request did not specify any
>   Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure
>   that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your
>   key restrictions.

In the MainActivity I have this code:

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

                    }
                }).setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(apiKey)).setApplicationName("Some Name").build();
```

In the cloud console I have an ApiKey for Android, with the package name set and the SHA-1 number obtained with keytool command.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After lot of trial and error, the thing which finally worked for me was changing **API KEY** restriction to **None** instead of **Android** from API Manager console and just save.
[image]

After doing the above step I am able to make search API call from my Android device using my API KEY.

Comment: It is the only solution that has worked for me at the time.

Comment: this can be considered as an work around, it works but the main problem with restricted key remains unsolved

Comment: @Exception this solution is not working for release version, it only working for debug phase. How to solve it for release version?.

Comment: This solution not working in release version.  Any others update ?

Comment: @AslamHossin, Are you doing all steps properly because for me the fix is working with release version.

Comment: Is there any risk  if i follow your procedure like i am requesting from android but API key is no restriction is ok ?

Comment: @AslamHossin is there any solution for release version?

Comment: @DarkLeonhart  yeah, finally I resolve it by creating browser key cause android key not working for release version for me.

Comment: Hi, you should try Ayman Al-Absi's solution, it works for me.

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same as explained above. Still not working for me.

Answer (score 21):

At last I found a solution for this problem :)

After creating API_KEY in Google Developer Console and restrict it with "Package name" and "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint", You have to provide these data in every youtube api request. Below the steps:

**1- get Package Name:**

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
```

**2- get SHA-1:**

```
private String getSHA1(String packageName){
    try {
        Signature[] signatures = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
        for (Signature signature: signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            return BaseEncoding.base16().encode(md.digest());
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**3- Prepare youtube api http header:**

```
youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        String SHA1 = getSHA1(packageName);

        request.getHeaders().set("X-Android-Package", packageName);
        request.getHeaders().set("X-Android-Cert",SHA1);
    }
}).setApplicationName(appName).build();
```

**4- Build your youtube api query as you like:**
For example to search for video:

```
YouTube.Search.List query;
query = youTube.search().list("id, snippet");
query.setKey(YOUR_API_KEY);
query.setType("video");
query.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
query.setQ(search keywords);
SearchListResponse response = query.execute();
List<SearchResult> results = response.getItems();
```

then process returned search results.

Comment: Where did you find info for putting the package and sha1 fingerprint there?

Comment: when you create Android Client key for your project, package name and SHA-1 is required.

Comment: Where did you find this document about hot to add package name and SHA1 fingerprint into a request headers?

Comment: Where did you found those cert and package headers specified in docs :)?

Comment: You may check steps in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode

Comment: Package name is equivalent to `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`

Comment: Did you use okhttp for this?

Comment: @AymanAl-Absi I tried your above solution. Still i'm getting error as ( "The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, com.example.somename and ZFzdtB22bpkKGc1kSgi0qxUPSWk=, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key.")

Comment: @JianLi Still no luck.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101196/android-youtube-api-v3-search-not-working

Comment: @Audumbar try sending the SHA1 in lower case hexcode format e.g:(AB:8A:CC:7R....) as (ab8acc7r...). worked for me.

Comment: Use this link for getting the SHA in all Android versions as packageManager.signatures is deprecated in Android P.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53407183/5095473

Answer (score 2):

Try to double check if you follow properly the setup when creating OAuth Credentials. And make sure you enable the YouTube Data API in your Developer Console.

Here the [steps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#installed-applications) that you need to do.

> 1. In the *Package name* field, enter your Android app's [package
>      name](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package)
> 2. In a terminal, run the [Keytool
>      utility](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html) to
>      get the SHA1 fingerprint for your digitally signed .apk file's public
>      certificate.

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v

> 3. Paste the SHA1 fingerprint into the form where requested.

I also found here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472782/upload-youtube-video-server-side) answered by a Googler that a user has to go through OAuth2. Because Service accounts are not supported in Data API v3.