# How to use PackageInfo.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES in API 28?

Tags: android, signature

The documentation of PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES says "This constant was deprecated in API level 28. Use GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES instead".

Unfortunately it was not secure and was easily hacked.

How can you use the new "GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES" introduced with Android P?

Comment: _"Unfortunately it was not secure and was easily hacked."_ Please elaborate.

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not as an edit to a question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In **API28 or higher** you should check for **multipleSigners** as well.

This function will do the job:
(*Works for Android 9.0 and lower*)

```kotlin
fun getApplicationSignature(packageName: String = context.packageName): List<String> {
    val signatureList: List<String>
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            // New signature
            val sig = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES).signingInfo
            signatureList = if (sig.hasMultipleSigners()) {
                // Send all with apkContentsSigners
                sig.apkContentsSigners.map {
                    val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                    digest.update(it.toByteArray())
                    bytesToHex(digest.digest())
                }
            } else {
                // Send one with signingCertificateHistory
                sig.signingCertificateHistory.map {
                    val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                    digest.update(it.toByteArray())
                    bytesToHex(digest.digest())
                }
            }
        } else {
            val sig = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures
            signatureList = sig.map {
                val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                digest.update(it.toByteArray())
                bytesToHex(digest.digest())
            }
        }

        return signatureList
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle error
    }
    return emptyList()
}
```

And `byteToHex` is:

```kotlin
fun bytesToHex(bytes: ByteArray): String {
    val hexArray = charArrayOf('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
    val hexChars = CharArray(bytes.size * 2)
    var v: Int
    for (j in bytes.indices) {
        v = bytes[j].toInt() and 0xFF
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v.ushr(4)]
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v and 0x0F]
    }
    return String(hexChars)
}
```

Comment: I've Implemented it in one of my app and Now over 100+ devices are returning different SHA1 resulting failed app;s api decryption.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I've used this in my SDK and many apps are using it. No problems till now. The vote shows that other's have found it helpful too. However, If there's anything wrong with the code that you know it, feel free to edit it.

Comment: A question. Why do you (and others) get the checksum of the signature? Can I just get its Public Key and check if it matches the one it should match? (the Public Key of my certificate)

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR** if your use case is that you're validating the calling package's signatures, you can still use GET_SIGNATURES in pre-api 28 securely as long as you validate all signers returned from the package manager (instead of stopping early when you find one that you trust).  In fact, google patched it in lollipop (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/f8986a989759c43c155ae64f9a3b36f670602521).

**Details:**
I believe your comment about GET_SIGNATURES being easily hacked is based on this vulnerability (https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Forristal-Android-FakeID-Vulnerability-Walkthrough.pdf).  Whereby android doesn't validate the trust chain prior to returning apk signers.

This is only a problem if you have code like this:

```
    private boolean validateCallingPackage(String: packageName) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo;
        try {
            packageInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }


        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            String hashedSignature = Utility.sha256hash(signature.toByteArray());
            if (validAppSignatureHashes.contains(hashedSignature)) {
              return true;  //THIS is the problematic code
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

The code is returning true if it finds any certificate that matches one from your whitelist.  With the android vulnerability, if the signatures contained a signature from a malicious signer, your code still returns true.

The mitigation for this vulnerability is to instead check ALL signatures returned from the package manager and return false if any of them aren't in your whitelist.  i.e.

```
    private boolean validateCallingPackage(String: packageName) {
        ...

        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            String hashedSignature = Utility.sha256hash(signature.toByteArray());
            if (!validAppSignatureHashes.contains(hashedSignature)) {
              return false; //FIXED
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. What about the new certificate API introduced in 28? Does the same rule, to check all signatures and see if one isn't in the allow list, still apply there?

Comment: @NimrodDayan I don't think so. The new API methods say they return certificates that the app has proven it is authorized to use. So you can just check with the first code on this answer: "When determining if a package is signed by a desired certificate, the returned array should be checked to determine if it is one of the entries." (from getSigningCertificateHistory()).

Comment: @ashoykh Didn't say it on the other comment, but goes now: thank you! Though, would you know how I can check only one certificate on the app with `GET_SIGNATURES`? I'd like to check if an app contains a certificate from the system (then it has system-signature permissions). Would you know if I need to create some method to check the chain of trust of all the certificates on the app and know which ones are valid and which are not, to then be able to check only one of them?

Answer (score 8):

My solution is:

In the gradle build set "compileSdkVersion 28" and "targetSdkVersion 28", now you can use this sample code:

```
try {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") final PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES);
        final Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signingInfo.getApkContentsSigners();
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            final String signatureBase64 = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            Log.d("Signature Base64", signatureBase64);
        }
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If strangely Android Studio does not recognize the constant GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES you can use the @SuppressLint ("WrongConstant") annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is very helpful. Why did you choose getApkContentsSigners instead of getSigningCertificateHistory? If an APK is only to be used in the Google Play store then getSigningCertificateHistory would be the best option right? and getApkContentsSigners if is going to have signatures for different stores?

Comment: I'll recommend to use Build.VERSION_CODES.P instead of hard coded value 28.

Answer (score 1):

Get package signatures:

```
private static List<String> getSignatures(@NonNull PackageManager pm, @NonNull String packageName) {
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES);
                    if (packageInfo == null
                            || packageInfo.signingInfo == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    if(packageInfo.signingInfo.hasMultipleSigners()){
                        return signatureDigest(packageInfo.signingInfo.getApkContentsSigners());
                    }
                    else{
                        return signatureDigest(packageInfo.signingInfo.getSigningCertificateHistory());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    @SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
                    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                    if (packageInfo == null
                            || packageInfo.signatures == null
                            || packageInfo.signatures.length == 0
                            || packageInfo.signatures[0] == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return signatureDigest(packageInfo.signatures);
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Convert signatures to list of hex strings:

```
        private static String signatureDigest(Signature sig) {
            byte[] signature = sig.toByteArray();
            try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
                byte[] digest = md.digest(signature);
                return BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(digest);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        private static List<String> signatureDigest(Signature[] sigList) {
            List<String> signaturesList= new ArrayList<>();
            for (Signature signature: sigList) {
                if(signature!=null) {
                    signaturesList.add(signatureDigest(signature));
                }
            }
           return signturesList;
        }
```

Compare package signatures with your whitelist:

```
    private static boolean verifyAppSignature(Context context) {
        //you should load approvedSignatures from a secure place not plain text
        List<String> approvedSignatures = new ArrayList<>();
        approvedSignatures.add("Your whitelist #1");
        approvedSignatures.add("Your whitelist #2");

        List<String> currentSignatures = getSignatures(context.getPackageManager(), context.getPackageName());
        if(currentSignatures!=null && currentSignatures.size()>0) {
            //first checking if no unapproved signatures exist
            for (String signatureHex : currentSignatures) {
                if (!approvedSignatures.contains(signatureHex)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            //now checking if any of approved signatures exist
            for (String signatureHex : currentSignatures) {
                if (approvedSignatures.contains(signatureHex)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get full signing key including colon.

code is

```
     private fun bytesToHex(bytes: ByteArray): String {
        val hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()
        val hexChars = CharArray((bytes.size * 3) - 1)
        var v: Int

        for(j in bytes.indices){
            v = bytes[j].toInt() and 0xFF
            hexChars[j * 3] = hexArray[v ushr 4]
            hexChars[j * 3 + 1] = hexArray[v and 0x0F]
            if(j < bytes.lastIndex){
                hexChars[j * 3 + 2] = ':'
            }
        }
        return String(hexChars)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this function can print the SHA-256,SHA-1,MD5 keys

```
private void printSHA(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        try {
            // get the package info that contains the key you want to print
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    context.getPackageName(),
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES
            );
            for (Signature signature : info.signingInfo.getApkContentsSigners()) {
                // you can use other algorithms like MD5, SHA-1 or SHA-256
                MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                sha.update(signature.toByteArray());

                // print the signing key SHA hash
                byte[] output = sha.digest();


                Log.e("KEY HASH (SHA-256):", Base64.encodeToString(output, Base64.DEFAULT));
                Log.e("KEY HASH Hex (SHA-256):", bytesToHex(output).toUpperCase());

                System.out.println("SHA-256 : ");
                System.out.println(bytesToHex(output).toUpperCase());
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e2) {

        }
    }
}
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte aByte : bytes) {
        builder.append(String.format("%02x", aByte));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```