# youtube search using youtube data api v3 in android

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, api-key, google-console-developer

I'm developing new app with this feature:
- user can search youtube videos from the app ..
I tried to use youtube api ..i created project in google console, generated api_key with android apps restriction(wrote app package & SHA-1 certificate fingerprint).
I used this link : 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=blabla&type=video&key=[api_key]
as I got from: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
but unfortunately I got this response and idk why

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=953519755004"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
 }
}
```

i hope any one can save my day

Comment: Check whether you have youtube data API enabled or not from [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com). Also, check whether you have a valid API key or not.

Comment: i enabled youtube data api and i have valid api key because i used it in something to else to make sure it's valid or not @AmritBhattacharjee

Answer (score 0):

you might need to set two request headers:

[Youtube API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543105/youtube-api-key)

youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        String SHA1 = getSHA1(packageName);

```
    request.getHeaders().set("X-Android-Package", packageName);
    request.getHeaders().set("X-Android-Cert",SHA1);
}
```

}).setApplicationName(appName).build();