# Youtube API GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, api, youtube

I'm Developing Android App using YOutube API.
I meet a problem like that:
**com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden**

When I search video. I try many link like [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100916/youtube-search-fail-with-googlejsonresponseexception-403-forbidden) but it not work for me.

I following these step:
1. Create Google console account.
2. Enable Youtube API V3
3. Create Dev Key(Android Key and Browser Key).

```
 query = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
        query.setKey(KEY);          
        query.setType("video");
        query.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)"); 
SearchListResponse response = query.execute();
```

Hope anyone help me resolve this issue.